# How would I run a unix command in a loop with variable data?

Tags: shell, unix

I'd like to run a unix command in a loop, replacing a variable for each iteration and then store the output into a file.

I'll be grabbing the HTTP headers of a series of URL's using `curl -I` and then I want each instance outputted to a new line of a file.
I know

I could store the output with `| cat` or redirect it into a file with `>`, but how would I run the loop?

I have a file with a list of URL's one per line (or I could comma separate them, alternatively).

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
while IFS= read -r url ; do
    curl -I "$url"
done < urls-to-query.txt > retrieved-headers.txt
```

(using the built-in `read` command, which reads a line from standard input — in this case redirected from `urls-to-query.txt` — and saves it to a variable — in this case `$url`).

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of URLs in a file:

```
http://url1.com
http://url2.com
```

You could run

cat inputfile | xargs curl -I >> outputfile

That would read each line of the input file and append the results for each row into the outputfile